# Installed app is grayed out and fails to open

Tags: ios, release

Our client will not be using the App Store to release their app, but instead is handling release in-house using Configurator 2. The problem is that when installation is complete the app is grayed out and when they launch it will immediately close out. Is this a signing or provisioning profile issue, or is there something else that could be causing this?

Comment: certificate issue, please re-check your crtificate

Comment: @Gagan_iOS The certificate that's being used is a distrobution certificate. What else should I be on the lookout for?

Comment: Recheck your process of creating IPA file. Check for plist, developer team.  Most probably certificate or configuration issue in setting.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is coming here in the future the way that I solved this was to add the iPad's UDID to our developer account and give them an IPA build using Ad Hoc. When adding more devices we had to rebuild the IPA after adding more UDIDs.